# Best way to automate the creation of PS-Mockups

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, mockup

I have designed several template pages in Indesign for sales purposes. Whilst most of the design stays the same, some elements (like logo and name) get individualized for each client.

Afterwards I export my pages as jpg-files and use them within a Photoshop-Mockup:
- Select the smart object
- replace content with chosen image
- export as jpg again

Now I am wondering if there is a more simple way to generate these mockup-exports in a more automated way. Anybody got experience with that?

Comment: Probably not, there's no real way to automate the updating in objects like that.